# Filter based on starting letter and presence of an asterisk in column

Tags: r

I have a large data frame, with 22 columns. I want to filter based on values in the second column, so if the value doesn't start with "X" I want to remove that row. Also I want to remove the row if this value in the second column contains an asterisk.

```
test <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
secondcolumn <- c("Xidfhsfd*isjdf", "Hsuhdfskdh", "Xwidfsoid", "X*sdkfjjhsd", "Xkdsfhsd", "Uskesfudhsk", "Sdfukhsdiu", "Osdfihsdoiuh", "Xsodifdsifj")
othercolumn <- c(3, 5, 7,2, 5, 8, 3, 0, 5)

df <- as.data.frame(test, secondcolumn, othercolumn)
```

How would this be done? In this example, I would want to remove the 1st, 2nd, 4th, 6th, 7th, 8th, and 9th rows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this works

```
# Condition 1: value start with "X"
cond1 <- grep("^X", d[, 2])
# Condition 2: doesn't contain "*"
cond2 <- grep("\\*", d[, 2], invert = TRUE)
# Rows where any of condition is true
wantedRows <- intersect(cond1, cond2)
# Table without those rows
d[wantedRows, ]
```

[image]

Comment: I may have been unclear, but I want it to start with X. Some values are NA so I thought by starting with X it would automatically remove these. How would that be done?

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to match 'X' at the start (`^`) of the string followed by one or more characters that are not a `*` (`[^*]+`) until the end (`$`) of the string to get the numeric index and subset rows based on that

```
df[grep("^X[^*]+$", df$secondcolumn),]
#  test secondcolumn othercolumn
#3    3    Xwidfsoid           7
#5    5     Xkdsfhsd           5
#9    9  Xsodifdsifj           5
```